# Supress environment message after logging into server?

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

After logging into an OpenSSH server from OS X, the following message is printed:

```
Last login: Sun Dec 27 15:47:12 2015 from 172.16.4.4
Environment:
  USER=jdoe
  LOGNAME=jdoe
  HOME=/Users/jdoe
  PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin
  MAIL=/var/mail/jdoe
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=172.16.4.4 56044 1522
  SSH_CONNECTION=172.16.4.4 56044 172.16.4.1 1522
  SSH_TTY=/dev/ttys006
  TERM=xterm-256color
```

The server is OS X 10.5 G5 Powermac (PowerPC). I run the server and give others accounts on it to test their software under the PowerPC architecture. The server is started with `sshd -d ...` because I sometimes need to check the Debug log file to troubleshoot issues.

I'm not sure if the message is coming from the client or the server. Searching for it has been tricky because of noise from irrelevant results.

How do I suppress the message at the client?

Comment: First you have to find *where* the message comes from.  If it's in your own `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile` file(s), that's easy.  If it comes, say, from `/etc/profile`, that's hard (unless you can change the login shell setting on your account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was answering the [same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34229227/2196426). So in short, this message is triggered by running `sshd` in debug moode (`-d` switch on command-line).

Check the init script or how do you start your server and make sure you don't give sshd such argument and restart `sshd` service.

Reasoning is behind the source code

- [accepting `-d` arguments](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshd.c#L1529)
- [writing environment variables in this format](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L1320)

Though from the previously mentioned question, in some environments this output can be triggered by some other knob, but I believe it is some rusty bug as the version of openssh that the OP was asking.

---

If you are interested in the logs, you can suppress this message by running server in normal mode and using `LogLevel DEBUG3` in your `sshd_config`.

Comment: *"... I was answering the same question on SO..."* - You should provide the answer here because the question is on-topic for Super User. Just [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/), but you should probably vote to close it on Stack Overflow since its off-topic for the site. Stack Overflow has become a dumping ground for off-topic and irrelevant questions.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. I do run ***`sshd`*** with `-d` option on the server. I do it because I give others accounts on the machine so they can test their software on the PowerPC architecture, and I sometimes need to look at the Debug log to see what's going on if they can't connect. Is there a way to suppress it at the client?

Comment: Yes. I pretty much did put all the relevant information here. If you are interested in logs, you can set up `LogLevel DEBUG3` in your `sshd_config` and run it without `-d`, which will result in the same logs, but you will not see such "greeting" on login.